# Installing CentOS7 / RHEL 7 on Proliant DL360e Gen8

Tags: centos, redhat, hp, hp-proliant

I found a fix for this after hours of digging on line.
Here is the main article i am using for a reference:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/118133

The RAID card which comes with this system basically has a proprietary driver for the B320i RAID card and intelligent provisioning BIOS software that gives you a GUI to install the OS. 
The problem is it doesn't register with RHEL 5 - RHEL 7. The only option it gives is to install a kernel driver by hand that you download from HP.

The work around I found for this is to shut off the Intelligent Provisioning software. 
Before you do anything do a boot up into the Intelligent Provisioning software and goto the settings area, go to the HP Smart Array setup and completely clear the RAID configuration, save and exit and reboot the system.

Next go into the BIOS it should show two options;
1) B320i - intelligent RAID card.
2) Intel SATA Card.

In the BIOS disable all the selections for the B320i (this should work for the B120i as well),
next select the boot order menu and place the Intel SATA card at the top of the boot order.
Make sure the PCI settings for the B320i are also disabled.
Exit the bios and save the settings.

Next boot up the server - when it comes to the selection of [F9 - setup]  [F10 - provision]  [F11 - boot menu] select the [F11].
It will go through a few settings and then it will prompt you with a menu, of something like 1 - 10 for different boot options. select 1) boot from DVD (or CDROM)

It will boot you up into the RHEL / CentOS install disk.
Once in the install menu - check the drive settings, it should show you the single drives you have listed.

Follow this document for setting up a RAID1 setting on your drives
http://www.ictdude.com/howto/install-centos-7-software-raid-lvm/

I hope this helps - maybe it will help save people some extra time from pulling their hair out.

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 1):

This is bad information.

If you're using a supported OS with an HP ProLiant DL360e server, you should probably use the HP Dynamic Smart Array driver disk - <s>[EL7 instructions here](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5249572&swItemId=MTX_7db7797756df4cd9825a5567e8&swEnvOid=4176)</s>.

Intelligent Provisioning is not necessary to bootstrap an HP box. It's handy for pre-OS firmware updates and array configuration, but I don't even use it for the OS-related portions.